# gnu-parallel: exec: perl: not found

Tags: bash, perl, ssh, parallel-processing, centos7

I have 3 EC2 instances with as OS Centos7.
I've installed parallel on one of the instances (server1).

It's possible to acces so no SSH issue

`ssh root@ip-10-0-xx-xx.xx-xx-1.compute.internal date` gave me the date.

```
ssh $SERVER echo works
works
```

Here I've created a ALL_SERVERS -file which contains the hostnames of my servers (root@ip-10-0-xx-xx.xx-xx-1.compute.internal).

Now I've written a short bash-script with the name test:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello'
```

I want to run this script (started on server1). also on server2 and server3 at the same time.

```
parallel ./test.sh --sshloginfile ALL_SERVERS
```

But it's just showing `Academic tradition requires you to cite works you base your article on....`
And after a few enters it's showing hello (only on my server1).

Can someone explaining what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
Also tried it without the file:

```
    parallel --sshlogin root@ip-10-0-xx-xx.xx-xx-1.compute.internal echo hello

output: bash: line 0: exec: perl: not found
```

I tried this too:

```
parallel --tag --nonall --slf ALL_SERVERS
```

Now I get:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-xx.xx-xx-1.compute.internal  bash: line 0: exec: perl: not found
root@ip-10-0-0-xx.xx-xx-1.compute.internal  bash: line 0: exec: perl: not found
```

Comment: It looks like perl is not installed on these instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
parallel ./test.sh --sshloginfile ALL_SERVERS
```

is not the same as:

```
parallel --sshloginfile ALL_SERVERS ./test.sh
```

You want the last.

`perl` must be installed on the workers.

```
ssh remote perl -e \''print "OK\n"'\'
```

must return OK.